# Поиск Фибоначчи

Tags: c, алгоритм, числа-фибоначчи

Объясните алгоритм поиска Фибоначчи, и по-возможности приведите код. Нагуглить что-либо понятное так и не удалось.

Comment: Первая же ссылка в гугле:

http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8

Comment: Не, не вычисление чисел Фибоначчи, а именно поиск в массиве методом Фибоначчи.
Вот что удалось нагуглить:
"В дереве Фибоначчи числа в дочерних узлах, отличаются от числа в родительском узле на одну и ту же величину, а именно на число Фибоначчи. Суть метода в том, что сравнивая наше искомое значение с очередным значением в массиве , мы не делим пополам новую зону поиска , как в бинарном поиске, а отступаем от предыдущего значения, с которым сравнивали, в нужную сторону на число Фибоначчи."

Comment: Изучите теорему Н.Н. Воробьева. Фибо-план, фибо-поиск максимального значения функции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

эээ основное преимущество замена деления на 2 на вычитание

т.е во временна когда апаратно вычесть было выгоднее чем поделить на 2 ( особенно когда не было битового сдвига на целых и деления на 2 как отдельной операции у плавающих)

у тебя из начально есть 4 числа разности между которыми позволяют продуцировать дальнейшии числа в исходном интервале.

а теперь ты просто ищеш экстремум функции - в зависимости в каком подинтервале там и продолжаеш генерацию разностей.

т.е для работы нужно 4 числа   a,b,c,d (в порядке возрастания)

где (с-a)/(d-a) = (b-a)/(c-a) - и близко (как приближение отношений соседних чисел фибоначи к золотому сечению)

можно увитеть что b-a ==d-с а оставшаяся серединка (с-b) есть следующее убывающее фибоначево.
и (c-b)  как большее а любая из частей (b-a)( либо (d-c)  что тоже самое) образуют следующую пару , для генерации в отрезке (a,c)(если поиск необходимо продолжить тут) следующей точни достаточно b'=c-(b-a) теперь d'=c и c'=b получается снова четвёрка точек 
a,b'(это с-(b-a)),c'( это b предыдущей итерации),d'(это с предыдущей итерации)

Comment: Путано, как-то. 

Не слишком очевидно, что описанные действия будут быстрее, чем программная реализация деления пополам (хотя, в отсутствии конкретной системы команд, мое замечание бездоказательно).

Comment: возмём 3  числа  упорядоченных по возрастанию так , что второе не_меньше среднего  арифмитического крайних.
 
вопрос: когда вычисление среднего арифмитического первых двух будет быстрее вычитания из второго разности  из третьего второго?

зы. особенно если числа плавающие .

ззы. если числа с фиксированной точкой ("в некотором смысле целые" - то да если мы весь интервал(начальный) разделили на некоторое число квантов("элементарных длин") и это некоторое число есть из последовательности фиббоначи , то мы можем просто идти назад по последовательности.